# flex 4: how can i properly integrate a flash design with a flex application?

Tags: flash, flex4

i hired a designer who knows flash but not flex, is there a way to properly integrate a flash design into a flex application?

can i load the swf and connect to specific events in specific elements of the swf ?

Using Adobe Flash Builder 4 beta2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Flash Builder 4 full version was released.

There is a flex component kit that can be downloaded and installed on adobe flash
to allow "convert symbol to flex component/container".

The information is at http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+Component+Kit+for+Flash

A video tutorial regarding the issue is at:
http://www.webkitchen.be/2008/12/12/video-tutorial-make-flex-components-with-flash-cs4/

please note that the latest flex component kit is for CS3 and it also works on flash cs4.